# C# DateTime has 'Z' when in memory, but not in SQL Db

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

When I've got a DateTime object in memory, it gets output to the screen as something like this:

"2015-12-28T20:47:01.9382255Z"

After storing it in the SQL database and retrieving it, the 'Z' is dropped:

"2015-12-28T20:47:01.9382255"

I'm trying to keep all the dates on my server in UTC time. Do I have to set up the SQL column some special way to store that 'Z' character?

I want the 'Z' to be stored, I do not want it to be dropped from the SQL store.

Comment: You probably really want a `DATETIMEOFFSET` type.

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Comment: @Crowcoder That's what did it! Post it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Z` means zulu time, which belongs on *textual* representation of a `DateTime` instance.

In Sql Server, neither `datetime` nor `datetime2` types have time zone support. That's why you can't save this on those types. But `datetimeoffset` has time zone support.

But you need to insert `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` on such a case like;

```
var dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2015-12-28T20:47:01.9382255Z");
```

In [Supported String Literal Formats for datetimeoffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx#Anchor_1) section;

> ISO Format - `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnn]Z (UTC)`
>
> Description - This format by ISO definition indicates the datetime
>   portion should be expressed in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). For
>   example, 1999-12-12 12:30:30.12345 -07:00 should be represented as
>   1999-12-12 19:30:30.12345Z.

Looks like that's the only way if you *really* wanna see the `Z` in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

datetime field is OK. The Z is there because

> If the time is in UTC, add a 'Z' directly after the time without a
>   space. 'Z' is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC"
>   is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would
>   be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".

Comment: I've got DateTimes on many objects and would like to avoid editing each one as I retrieve from the Db.

Comment: Datetime value is stored as a number (that makes search faster) so in this case the value you have displayed is just a string representation.